# How Mysql Query Plan is generated?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

Mysql before executing a query with multiple joins. It creates multiple query plan and find the lowest cost plan to execute the query(approx).

My questions are

1. How the query plan is generated on what basis(like no of fields in the where condition for a particular table)
2. Is there any formula(or steps) to generate query plan by ourself

Answer (score 2):

The answer is evolving.  More "cost" analysis went into 5.7, still more into 8.0.  There is more to go, such as "histograms" instead of a single number for cardinality.

In the case of joins, MySQL has always pursued all permutations of ordering for the tables.  However, it has an aggressive pruning strategy that keeps it from actually doing "all".  (Key-value (EAV) stores defeat this, but there is a tunable to help.)

The main statistic used is an estimate of the cardinality for each index.  This is found by 'randomly' probing the BTree for the index.  These probes and the retention of the data was significantly improved in 5.6.

Generally, when you are joining multiple tables, the `WHERE` clause has a lot of sway in saying which table to start with.  If there is no `WHERE`, then the "smallest" table is picked as the first.  (This is sometimes not the best.)

There are a few tricks to guide the Optimizer.  *These are generally a bad idea.  What helps today may hurt tomorrow.*

`STRAIGHT_JOIN` -- do the joins in the order given.
`USE/IGNORE INDEX` -- give preference to/against specified index(es).
`FORCE INDEX` -- If at all possible, use this index.

And 8.0 has more.

And there are tricks.  A 'derived' table is allow to ignore `ORDER BY`.  But you can trick it into doing the sort by adding a `LIMIT` with a huge value.

Comment: I'm one of your consistent follower in stack overflow. You are really good in Mysql. Do you have any complete reference material for MySql optimiser  made by yourself .

Comment: @vinieth - Thanks for the praise.  Everything I have is here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/ .  Occasionally I update/augment it; feel free to point out mistakes or ask for new topics.  The set is very much aimed at helping answer questions on this an other forums.

Comment: @vinieth - And...  See especially the "Cookbook" link.  It attempts to approach your Question from a different point of view.  Your Question asks "how things work"; my Cookbook tries to answer the 'practical' question of "how do I build the best index".  Though my docs may _incidentally_ give insight into how things work; their focus is on how to effectively use MySQL.

Comment: @vinieth - For example... Though I could talk at length about how `PARTITIONing` _works_, that would not convey the fact (in my opinion) that the feature is virtually worthless.  So, my Partition blog focuses on how to make use of it while de-emphasizing the useless parts of the feature.